# Properties of finite quotients of quasi-projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a (smooth) quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb C$.

One can consider the stacky quotient $[X/G]$ or the "classical" quotient $X/G$. In general, $[X/G]$ is not a scheme (not even an algebraic space), whereas $X/G$ is always a quasi-projective variety.

I've been wondering about the precise relation between these two objects.

My guess is that $X/G$ is the "coarse moduli space" of the DM stack $[X/G]$. Is this correct?

Comment: $X/G$ is the coarse moduli space of $[X/G]$ when it is a categorical quotient. For more details see Mumford--Fogarty--Kirwan.

Comment: @Sasha Isn't $X/G$ always the categorical quotient in the quasi-projective case?

Comment: @Anton: For finite group acting on a quasi-projective variety in char 0 --- yes. But not only in this case.